UniswapV3 Add Liquidity code is failing
I am currently working on uniswapv3 and  encountering issues with the createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary and NonfungiblePositionManager.mint function. when i call the function of NonfungiblePositionManager.mint function the transaction are reverted.. And the uniswapv3pool address generated by the createAndInitializePoolIfNecessary contract and address get by the Liquiditymanagement contract are not matched.. Also guide me the proper workflow of it at smart contract level..
